# Facebook: "(#2635) You are calling a deprecated version of the Ads API. Please update to the latest version: v7.0."

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

When attempting to call:

```
        FB.api(`/${authResponse.userID}/adaccounts`, accountsResponse => {
            console.log('accountsResponse ', accountsResponse);
        });
```

as per the docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/adaccounts/), we get this response:

```
error:
code: 2635
fbtrace_id: "AtKWTpvIoYCi5YXpg-2Xr0g"
message: "(#2635) You are calling a deprecated version of the Ads API. Please update to the latest version: v7.0."
type: "OAuthException"
```

The trouble is, we are using version v8.0, which is, contrary to the information contained in this erroneous error message, the latest version!

Here is how we load the SDK (using Nuxt):

```
        {
            // replaced "sdk.js" with "all.js" due to "init not called with valid version"
            // problem solved... but apparently this is bad
            // see https://gist.github.com/tpai/602898fe0d3d630f0099d58856cef352
            // other proposed solutions fail.
            src: 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js',
            crossorigin: 'anonymous',
            async: true,
            defer: true,
        }
```

So this is a bit strange, but we can't get the suggested "sdk.js" to work at all, and at least this loads and allows us to call FB.login() successfully.

and here is how we init:

```
                        FB.init({
                            appId,
                            autoLogAppEvents: true,
                            xfbml: true,
                            version: 'v8.0',
                        });
```

Changing this version number to 'v7.0' has no effect.

Comment: _“but we can't get the suggested "sdk.js" to work at all”_ - why not, what problems are you running into? Just arbitrarily switching to an outdated version does not sound like a clever thing to do.

Comment: as stated in the comment above:
replaced "sdk.js" with "all.js" due to "init not called with valid version"
we are not using an outdated version.  the version is specified as 8.0.

Comment: I meant the SDK version that is outdated. `all.js` has been “replaced” by `skd.js` quite a while back already. They kept the old one, so as to not break functionality on sites that embed it - but for any current development, one should really stick to the new one.

Comment: right. for unknown reasons, loading this sdk.js dynamically using Nuxt's head() function was failing, but, bizarrely, loading all.js was working fine, and calling FB.init(), FB.login(), FB.getLoginStatus(), FB.logout(), FB.api(), FB.api(userId) using all.js all work great.... just not FB.api(`userID/adaccounts`), which throws the above mentioned extremely confusing and totally wrong error message.

Answer (score 1):

So, it seems that loading sdk.js in head(), rather than using a  tag, confuses everyone somehow. Since  makes Vue unhappy, we had to find another workaround, which we did, [right here](https://gist.github.com/tpai/602898fe0d3d630f0099d58856cef352):

```
mounted() {
        const fbDiv = document.createElement('div');
        fbDiv.id = 'fb-root';
        document.body.appendChild(fbDiv);
        // run after sdk is loaded
        window.fbAsyncInit = () => {
            FB.init({
                appId,
                autoLogAppEvents: true,
                xfbml: true,
                version: 'v8.0',
            });
        };
        // inject sdk.js
        (function (d, script) {
            script = d.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.async = true;
            script.src = `https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v8.0&appId=${fbAppId}&autoLogAppEvents=1`;
            d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
        })(document);
    }
```